# BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero - Why?

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, rsa, badpaddingexception

I need to write a java code which encrypt/decrypt messages using a private/public key given by a customer.
Here is what I did:

- I got from the customer the private key which is in PKCS#1 format (It starts with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----)
- I converted it into PKCS#8 using the following command:

  ```
  openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in private_pkcs1.key -out private_pkcs8.key
  ```
- Now I have the private key in PKCS#8 format (which starts with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----)
- I have extracted the public key out of the private key (tried with both formats, and I got the same public key) using the following command:

  ```
  openssl rsa -in private_pkcs8.key -pubout > public.key
  ```
- I have written the following method to read the private key the private_pkcs8.key file:

  ```
  private static PrivateKey readPrivateKey(String filename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException
  {
  File file = new File(filename);
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
  byte[] keyBytes = new byte[ new Long(file.length()).intValue() ];
  in.read(keyBytes);
  in.close();

  String strPrivateKey = new String(keyBytes, "UTF-8").replaceAll("(-+BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-+\\r?\\n|-+END PRIVATE KEY-+\\r?\\n?)", "");
  PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(strPrivateKey));
  KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  return keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
  }
  ```
- I have written the following method to read the public key from the public.key file

  ```
  private static PublicKey readPublicKey(String filename) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException
  {
  File file = new File(filename);
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
  byte[] keyBytes = new byte[ new Long(file.length()).intValue() ];
  in.read(keyBytes);
  in.close();

  String strPublicKey = new String(keyBytes, "UTF-8").replaceAll("(-+BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n|-+END PUBLIC KEY-+\\r?\\n?)", "");
  X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(strPublicKey));
  KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
  return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
  }
  ```
- I have written the following encrypt method

  ```
  private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] message, Key key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
  {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHEM);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

  return cipher.doFinal(message);
  }
  ```
- I have written the following decrypt method

  ```
  private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message, Key key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
  {
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHEM);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

  return cipher.doFinal(message);
  }
  ```
- I have written the following main test application which tries to encrypt a simple string and decrypt it back.

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, SignatureException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
  {
  readKeys();

  String messageToEncrypt = "This is the string I want to test";

  log("Original Message: " + messageToEncrypt);
  byte[] originalBytes = messageToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");

  byte[] encriptedBytes = encrypt(originalBytes, privateKey);
  byte[] decriptedMessage = decrypt(encriptedBytes, publicKey);

  log("Decripted Message: " + new String(decriptedMessage));
  }
  ```
- The encryption was OK, but when I try to decrypt it back to the original message I got the following exception:

  ```
  Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.a(DashoA13*..)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
  at com.company.encryption.utils.RsaUtils.decrypt(RsaUtils.java:95)
  at com.company.encryption.utils.RsaUtils.main(RsaUtils.java:108)
  ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
  JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
  ```

Note that the JVM also crashes, which is very strange.

- When I have replaced the private/public keys and used KeyPairGenerator instead, all was OK. This brings me to the conclusion that something is wrong with the keys, or the way I read the keys, or the algorithm I use to encrypt / decrypt. ( I have tried with "RSA", "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" - with no luck)

I have spent more than 2 days on this issue. I made sure I use the same public/private pair of keys, I didn't try to convert byte[] to String. I have done everything "by the book"

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. Is there some question I could ask my customer about the keys, that will help me solve this mystery? Why the JVM also crashes?

Thanks
Guy Hudara

Answer (score 0):

In asymmetric ciphers one encrypts with public key and decrypts with private key. This way it ensures that anyone can encrypt the message with commonly known public key, but only holder of the private key may decrypt it.

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = encrypt(originalBytes, publicKey);
byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(encryptedBytes, privateKey);
```

Comment: Generally speaking you are correct. But in my case, I don't care that "anyone" can encrypt the message. I want my client to be sure that this message was sent by me, and only by me. What about my original question? Why do I get this exception? Any idea?

Comment: If you want authentication you should be using signature instead of encryption. Signature is produced with a private key and verified with a public key. To your original question - Sun security provider probably doesn't support decryption with a public key, hence the error.

Comment: I have tried to encrypt with public key - as you suggested - and got the same exception (BadPaddingException) in the encrypt method. Moreover, if I don't try to load the Keys from file, but I generate my own pair of keys (Using the KeyPairGenerator) everything works fine, including decryption with public key. This makes me think that there is something wrong with my public key. Maybe the algorithm/mode/padding I use does not match the key? How can I verify this?

Comment: I assume openssl and KeyFactory.generatePublic() complained, if that would be a key corruption problem.

Comment: No one complained )-:

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem. Solved by regenerating public key.